# Android Studio Designer preview does not show correct dimensions

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, xamarin, dimensions

I have a strange issue with Android Studio Designer.

I am trying to work on my layouts so that they fit for multiple screen sizes and density.

I am to the point where I need to set different text sizes to different labels. Some bigger, some smaller.

So I created a couple of `dimens.xml` files (one for small and one for large, not forgetting one by default) just so that I can see it would look on a very small device and fairly large device.

Using the designer and a Nexus 4 I find myself in a strange situation: while the preview with "Nexus 4" within Android Studio shows good sizes, the final result is horrible.
First, I found that either my Nexus 4 or my Galaxy Note 3 uses `large/dimens.xml.` They both use the same : `value/dimens.xml`. How come ? Not the same screen size, not even the same density and resolution !

So even though I set specific dimensions in my XMLs and even though Android Studio Designer shows good ratios on the "Nexus 4", my application does not reflect, at all, what I can see on the designer ! Why ?
Smaller texts look large, bigger texts look too large ... all in all, everything is disproportionate both on my Nexus 4 and GN 3 !

Further details : I am using Android Studio to design all my layouts and resources. I use Xamarin for my work. I made sure all XML files are exactly same on both IDE. To prove that I am not wrong, both IDE designers showing the result on the same device preview (Nexus 4) shows exactly the same ratios. Meaning, the correct dimensions are being use. So why am I not seeing the same thing on my "real" Nexus 4 ?

Thanks for the help !